# Launch elasticsearch server using python code

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyelasticsearch

I would like to write a script in python which creates an elasticsearch server at localhost 9200. All of the examples that I find online regard connecting to an existing elasticsearch instance running at localhost 9200. My motivation is that I don't want to have to use the command line to run or shutoff the server.

Basically replace this line

```
 bin/elasticsearch
```

with something in python.

UPDATE: I tried the following

```
subprocess.popen('elasticsearch-1.4.0/bin/elasticsearch')
```

However, I am getting the error "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'popen'"

My application.py file will run the elasticsearch service and then create another service which I can use to make calls to the elasticsearch server.

Could anyone provide a code snippet of how I would go about creating the elasticsearch instance programmatically? Are there any existing projects that do this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: with a capital P : subprocess.Popen(...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from os import popen
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen('elasticsearch-1.4.0/bin/elasticsearch')
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
from os import popen
popen('bin/elasticsearch')
```

Comment: popen allows me to run elasticsearch, but then the lines of code after popen don't get executed. I think that the program is hanging on popen. Should I spawn a separate thread?

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch takes some time to start. That's why you may not be able to see the connection and run the following commands immediately. Try running the script again after a few seconds.